# Set parent <div> width of children <div> using CSS

Tags: css, html

I have a three column markup for which the middle column **#palette**( elastic column) has following innerHTML markup  snippet

```
<div id="palette">
<div id="wrapper" style="left: -354px; top: 0px;">
  <div id="colours">
    <ul>
      <li class="swatch"><a tite="Beige" style="background-color:beige;"  class="label" href="javascript:void(0);"><span>&nbsp;</span></a></li>
      <li class="swatch"><a tite="Bisque" ... class="label" href="javascript:void(0);"><span>&nbsp;</span></a></li>
      <li class="swatch"><a tite="Brown" style="background-color:brown;" class="label" href="javascript:void(0);"><span>&nbsp;</span></a></li>
      <li class="swatch"><a tite="Coral" style="background-color:coral;" onclick="setColouringColour(this);" class="label" href="javascript:void(0);"><span>&nbsp;</span></a></li>
      ....
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="brush-sizes"> <span style="width:16px; height:16px;" ><span>16</span></a></span> <span class="brush badge" style="width:32px; height:32px;"><a...><span>32</span></a></span> <span class="brush badge" style="width:64px; height:64px;"><a...><span>64</span></a></span> </div>
  <div id="brushes"> <a class="selected btn btn-mini"...>&nbsp;</a> <a class="btn btn-mini">&nbsp;</a> </div>
</div>
```

Where the following CSS rules apply

```
#palette {
float: left;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
width: 100%; overflow:hidden;
}
#wrapper {
 display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
top: 0 !important;
white-space: nowrap;
width: auto;
}
```

> Note: **#palette** is **overflow:hidden** so that **#wrapper** can be
>   scrolled using **left:*n*px;**. The children  inside
>   **#wrapper** are all **display:inline-block; clear:none;**

The problem I am having is that **#wrapper** is not at "full width" of its children...thus I can't seem to be able to scroll to the very end.

What is the source of the problem here and how can I fix it using **CSS ONLY**( can it be accomplished CSS only?)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I needed to set one of the 2 remaining ***< div >*** to a fixed width and also tried setting the max- and min- width appropriately. Don't know why that worked